# Is there an easier way to manipulate GRUB 2 entries?

Tags: grub2

Using GRUB 2 is harder than GRUB 1 for these use cases:

- It looks like if I want to reorder GRUB 2 menu entries appear in the selection window, I have to rename the files in "**/etc/grub.d/**" directory.
- If I have to change boot order, I first have to look in "**/boot/grub/grub.cfg**", check when the entry I want to be default appears, then set the `GRUB_DEFAULT` parameter in "**/etc/default/grub**" to match it (counting from 0).

The old GRUB used to allow me to do all of this by just moving text entries in "**/boot/grub/menu.lst**" around. This much-simpler way kept me using GRUB 1 for a while. This makes me wonder if there's a specialized tool to make all of this easier.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Robbins,creator of Gentoo Linux, has been working on something called "Boot-Update" for Funtoo.  I've not tried it.  Seems to be what you are looking for.

http://docs.funtoo.org/wiki/Funtoo_Boot-Update

Comment: This looks like the `update-grub` script in Ubuntu, which doesn't allow customizing Grub, which I think the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

boot-update ( http://www.funtoo.org/wiki/Boot-Update ) is working and generates great results for funtoo operating systems and for dualboot with Windows as far as I know. Other Configurations still need to be tested but it should work too, if you gave it a try let us know, but I guess just porting boot-update to other systems isn't that easy, as the output is colored by an internal function you have to copy with or implement :) For further questions you are welcome to ask here or at irc freenode #funtoo.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that grub2 is anyhow harder compared to grub1. It's just very different.

Having different files in `/etc/grub.d/` looks more clever for me, you don't need to reconfigure it each time. That is the goal. You setup settings you need once and then new changes will get right place in config automatically with `grub2-mkconfig` but it's offtopic so there are also lots of additional tools to make it easier. For example [Grub customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer).

Answer (score -1):

Grub 2 is horrid. I threw it out and use extlinux (part of syslinux package) from now on. To answer your question, there is no easier way.

Comment: +1 to this, as for today (March 2015). Grub-Customizer adds multiple unneeded menu entries, and requires GUI. I hope some simple method (maybe some short script) will be open sourced by somebody for, at least, renaming a menu entry.